# Sympy .coeff_all() returned list is not readable by scipy

Tags: scipy, sympy, coefficients, poly

I have question about the data type of the result returned by Sympy Poly.all_coeffs(). I have started to use Sympy just recently. 
My Sympy transfer function is following:

[image]

Then I run this code:

```
n,d = fraction(Gs)
num = Poly(n,s)
den = Poly(d,s)
num_c = num.all_coeffs()
den_c = den.all_coeffs()
```

I get:

[image]

Then I run this code:

```
from scipy import signal
#nu = [5000000.0]
#de = [4.99, 509000.0]
nu = num_c
de = den_c
sys = signal.lti(nu, de)
w,mag,phase = signal.bode(sys)
plt.plot(w/(2*np.pi), mag)
```

and the result is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-131-fb960684259c> in <module>
      4 nu = num_c
      5 de = den_c
----> 6 sys = signal.lti(nu, de)
```

But if I use those commented line 'nu' and 'de' straight python lists instead, the program works. So what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Why did you just show a bit the error?  Why not the full message, maybe even the full traceback!

```
In [60]: sys = signal.lti(num_c, den_c)                                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-21f71ecd8884> in <module>
----> 1 sys = signal.lti(num_c, den_c)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/signal/ltisys.py in __init__(self, *system, **kwargs)
    590         self._den = None
    591 
--> 592         self.num, self.den = normalize(*system)
    593 
    594     def __repr__(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/signal/filter_design.py in normalize(b, a)
   1609     leading_zeros = 0
   1610     for col in num.T:
-> 1611         if np.allclose(col, 0, atol=1e-14):
   1612             leading_zeros += 1
   1613         else:

<__array_function__ internals> in allclose(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in allclose(a, b, rtol, atol, equal_nan)
   2169 
   2170     """
-> 2171     res = all(isclose(a, b, rtol=rtol, atol=atol, equal_nan=equal_nan))
   2172     return bool(res)
   2173 

<__array_function__ internals> in isclose(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in isclose(a, b, rtol, atol, equal_nan)
   2267     y = array(y, dtype=dt, copy=False, subok=True)
   2268 
-> 2269     xfin = isfinite(x)
   2270     yfin = isfinite(y)
   2271     if all(xfin) and all(yfin):

TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Now look at the elements of the `num_c` list (same for `den_c`):

```
In [55]: num_c[0]                                                                                         
Out[55]: 500000.000000000

In [56]: type(_)                                                                                          
Out[56]: sympy.core.numbers.Float
```

The `scipy` code is doing `numpy` testing on the inputs.  So it's first turned the lists into arrays:

```
In [61]: np.array(num_c)                                                                                  
Out[61]: array([500000.000000000], dtype=object)
```

This array contains `sympy` object(s).  It can't cast that to numpy float with 'safe'.  But an explicit `astype` uses `unsafe` as the default:

```
In [63]: np.array(num_c).astype(float)                                                                    
Out[63]: array([500000.])
```

So lets convert both lists into valid numpy float arrays:

```
In [64]: sys = signal.lti(np.array(num_c).astype(float), np.array(den_c).astype(float))                   

In [65]: sys                                                                                              
Out[65]: 
TransferFunctionContinuous(
array([100200.4008016]),
array([1.00000000e+00, 1.02004008e+05]),
dt: None
)
```

Conversion in a list comprehension also works:

```
sys = signal.lti([float(i) for i in num_c],[float(i) for i in den_c])
```

Comment: I thought to save some space by having only the beginning that says already that it is a type error. But next time I promise I'll put the whole thing :). Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: You can also use `np.array(num_c, dtype=float)`, which is probably the preferred way to do this.

Comment: I started with `np.array(...)` to highlight the fact that, by default, the `scipy` is getting an array with sympy floats, not the numpy ones it needs.  I suspect either way is good.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to conver sympy objects to floats / lists of floats.

Comment: Yes, I think so too. Tried already to convert list element in for loop, but got error: TypeError: 'Poly' object is not iterable